# Duplicate jQuery library when using Rails Assets

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I like to include bower, node packages in my Rails app using [Rails Assets](http://rails-assets.org):

```
source 'https://rails-assets.org' do
  gem 'rails-assets-colorbox'
end

# ...

gem 'jquery-rails'
```

Now when I did run `bundle install` I got the following output:

> ...
>   Using pg 0.18.1
>   **Installing rails-assets-jquery 2.1.3**
>   **Installing rails-assets-colorbox 1.6.0**
>   Using ruby-graphviz 1.0.9
>   ...

Now I am already using the `jquery-rails` plugin which is obviously a wrapper of jquery but which, I believe, does more advanced rails-related stuff too.

So now I seem to have two versions of jquery in my Rails app which is not ideal.

My questions is now whether I can get rid of `jquery-rails` and just include `rails-assets-jquery` in my `Gemfile`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not using [jquery-ujs](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs), you may not use the gem `jquery-rails` at all.

> jquery-ujs wires event handlers to eligible DOM elements to provide
>   enhanced functionality. In most cases, the eligible DOM elements are
>   identified by HTML5 data attributes.

For example, If you have a HTML form, and if you want to submit your HTML form in a Ajax way (instead of a pageload), you'd have to add :remote=>true attribute in to your form_for. Your controller, now can respond to the ajax request, that could be a HTML Embed. This would help you to improve user experience, while still keeping the client-side js light.

jquery-ujs would fire events that you could handle, for example `ajax:success` `ajax:error`.

If you are new to rails, try going to this walk through.

1. https://robots.thoughtbot.com/a-tour-of-rails-jquery-ujs
2. http://www.alfajango.com/blog/rails-3-remote-links-and-forms/

You may also prefer to include jQuery using CDN, if you only want to use jQuery but not jquery-ujs. Its more efficient.

Comment: can you explain why jquery-ujs makes the difference?